# Handling 500 Internal Server Error from DomDocument in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, exception, laravel-5

The library I wrote for Laravel uses `DomDocument`.

I use this library under my Controller, and its namespace is `app/Services/Verify/`. The library gets initialized and used when I put it some inputs into a form.

When the library fails, Laravel would fail the way it would - returning the following message: `Whoops, looks like something went wrong.`

I use the following regex to validate the URL on the client-side - `'our_team_link' => 'required|url|regex:/^http:\/\/www\.ugcleague\.com\/team_page\.cfm\?clan_id=\d+$/'`

Below is my DomXPath code for the above URL.

```
    // Generate our team's HTML file
    $this->ourTeamHTML = new \DomDocument;
    $this->ourTeamHTML->loadHTMLFile($this->ourTeamURL);
```

Most of the time the web app works just fine. However, there are cases where even if they type in a URL that is valid by the regex, there are indeed URLs that don't exist (that still get past the regex), and an error like the following gets returned:

```
PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(http://www.ugcleague.com/team_page.cfm?clan_id=8831111118): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
 in /Users/loop/Code/laravel/app/Services/Verify/ScrapeUGC.php on line 49

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(http://www.ugcleague.com/team_page.cfm?clan_id=8831111118): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
 in /Users/loop/Code/laravel/app/Services/Verify/ScrapeUGC.php on line 49
```

Laravel would be linked to the `Whoops, looks like something went wrong` page.

This confuses the user. I would like to instead return a more descriptive error, that would say, perhaps, "this team does not exist."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could handle this in Laravel app/Exceptions/Hnadler.php

NB: I have looked in the option of using DOMException handler which is available in PHP, however the error message you are getting in not really and exception by an I/O Warning.

This what PHP native DomException looks like:

```
/**
 * DOM operations raise exceptions under particular circumstances, i.e.,
 * when an operation is impossible to perform for logical reasons.
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/class.domexception.php
 */
class DOMException extends Exception  {

    /**
     * @var
     * (PHP 5)<br/>
     * An integer indicating the type of error generated
     * @link http://php.net/manual/en/class.domexception.php#domexception.props.code
     */
    public $code;
}
```

So I came up with this because we can not use DomException to dictate this error since its not an Exception, you can add this in your app/Exceptions/Handler.php

```
 <?php

 namespace App\Exceptions;

 use Exception;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;


 class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
 {
      /**
      * A list of the exception types that should not be reported.
      *
      * @var array
      */
      protected $dontReport = [
         \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException::class,
      ];

     /**
     * Report or log an exception.
     *
     * This is a great spot to send exceptions to Sentry, Bugsnag, etc.
     *
     * @param  \Exception  $e
     * @return void
     */
     public function report(Exception $e)
     {
         return parent::report($e);
     }

    /**
    * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
    *
    * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
    * @param  \Exception  $e
    * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
    */
    public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {

        $message = $e->getMessage();

        if (str_contains($message, 'DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): I/O warning')) {
             return redirect($request->fullUrl())->with('error', "This team does not exist");
        }


       //We could also handle DomException like so, but not Dom warning 
       if ($e instanceof \DomException){
            return redirect($request->fullUrl())->with('error', "Your friendly message here");
        }


     }
}
```

NB: Be careful when modifying Handler.php, you might start having blank pages instead of Laravel whoops or errors if you don't know what you are doing. You can make a backup somewhere if you are unsure.

Comment: Thank you this is precisely what I meant

Comment: Hi digit. Pardon my questions. I have received blank pages before when encountering an exception in Laravel - that's before I modified the `Handler.php`. What would be the cause of that behavior?

Comment: Since you didn't modify you handler.php probably permission issues like not setting permission on storage folder

Comment: Ultimately we determined it was a namespace issue with a library we were using (we didn't add a \ before the class initialization as well as not using `__construct` within the constructor of the custom class). It's weird Laravel didn't tell us any errors or exceptions; it only served us a blank page.

Comment: Could be other reasons dough. Maybe a bad package you installed or even a bad custom middleware

Comment: Oh I see that's wired.

Answer (score 0):

There is a php function you will want to use to disable libxml errors.

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
```

Now when you are done processing your script, you will need to get any errors generated by using...

```
$errors = libxml_get_errors();
```

That would return an array so you can now check it with...

```
if(count($errors) > 0) {
    echo 'This team does not exist';
} else {
    echo 'Successful';
}

// Be sure to clear errors
libxml_clear_errors();
```

You will most likely need to loop through that array and process each error to be sure it's the specific error you are looking for.  When working with `DOMDocument`, you are bound to get a bunch of notices/warnings every time it finds something it doesn't like about invalid HTML/XML.

Comment: Hi user. Thanks. How should I make Laravel handle these errors? EDIT: The error I am getting actually is a `500 Internal Server Error` (for inexistant URL paths) from DomDocument.

Comment: Laravel has its own error handler where it will detect any errors and throw an `ErrorException`.  Just setting `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);` will handle that and allow you to do as you please with any libxml errors.

Comment: Yep.. Just saw this. Do you know why my error page is simply just the HTML markup? http://puu.sh/iyDgn/d6e96a6789.png

Comment: Not really too sure.  Check in your browser console for the header `Content-Type` on the response.  It's probably `text/plain` so that's what the browser gives you.

Comment: Bingo. The page itself is a 500 status as well.